# How can I add special mathematical and statistical characters and graphics in texview on Android?

Tags: android, textview, special-characters

I have to add mathematical and statistical special characters, equations and graphics to my android application. How can I do that? Can I add these in TextView or something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course.

Since `TextView` in Android supports [`UTF-8`](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), you can embed non typical characters such as :

```
TextView text_view = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.text_field);
text_view.setText("1 ≠ 2 ; 1 ÷ 1 = 1 ; ↦ ; ∑ ; ⋉, ⋊ ; ⋂ ; ∈");
```

And `text_view` defined as follow :

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text_field"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

You can find a list of the mathematical [UTF-8 symbols on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols).